# ViewChildren doesn't bind in ngFor

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a simple template:

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of allSkills | async ">
    <div class="skill-chart-with-img">
        <skill-chart-view></skill-chart-view>
        <div #skillImg>
            some data
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to bind on #skillImg, I have an empty QueryList:

```
@ViewChildren("skillImg") private skillImgs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.skillImgs.forEach((skill: ElementRef) => {
           //some work with skill
        });
}
```

Maybe I miss something or my task have a better solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was in async data. The solution is to subscribe on QueryList changes

Example:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.skillImgs.changes
        .subscribe(() => console.log(this.skillImgs));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**: You have to check whether async works properly or not. Because its hard to identify any problem if associated with async pipe. But other than it, ViewChildren works with *ngFor as shown below,

```
export class App {

  @ViewChildren("skillImg") private skillImgs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {}


    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
            this.skillImgs.forEach((skill: ElementRef) => {
                 this.renderer.setElementStyle(skill.nativeElement,"background","yellow");    
            });
    }

}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/pI35tx9gXZFO1sXj9Obm?p=preview

Comment: I post answer below

Answer (score 1):

This issue only occurs on the dev mode. There are a number of ways by which you can handle this.

1. Explicit change detection

```
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.skillImgs.changes.subscribe(() => {
    //make changes here
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  })
}
```

2. Use Promise

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.skillImgs.changes.subscribe(()=>{
            Promise.resolve().then(()=>{
               //make changes here
            });
         })
     }
```

3. Timeout

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.skillImgs.changes.subscribe(()=>{
      settimeout(()=>{
        //make changes here
      });
    }, 0)’
  }
```

Reference from [here](https://angular.io/errors/NG0100)