# How to interpolate values to angular refs?

Tags: angular

I have some elements created by an *ngFor like:

```html
<div *ngFor="let element of elements">
  <p #someReference>Element is {{ element }} etc.<p>
</div>
```

You get the idea.
I want to be able to change the references' names dynamically like:

```html
<p #someReference1>Element is {{ element }} etc.<p>
<p #someReference2>Element is {{ element }} etc.<p>
<p #someReference3>Element is {{ element }} etc.<p>
<!-- etc. -->
```

Based on some property. Is this possible?

Comment: you can refer this stackoverflow question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951165/viewchildren-doesnt-bind-in-ngfor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can,

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elements; let i = index;">
  <p #someReference{{i}}>Element is {{ element }} etc.<p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this seems to work. However, I would also like to know how to call (refer to) them in the template.

Comment: Depends on the method you wanted to implement actually

Comment: Yes, that's for another question

Answer (score 1):

You can make every paragraph as a component.

Or you can use index of ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elements; let i = index">
  <p #someReference_i>Element is {{ element }} etc.<p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this works. But like my other comment on @Kirubel's answer, I would like to know how to call (refer to) them.

Answer (score 0):

#someReference is already unique for each item. You can use it inside your *ngFor.
also, you can use it like this to get your elements list and do whatever you want.

```
  @ViewChildren('someReference ') someReference : QueryList<ElementRef>;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.someReference.forEach((element)=> {
      console.log(element);
    })
  }
```